# should I move to windows azure to save on costs for magento?

Tags: linux, magento, azure, magento-1.7

Currently I am payin 374 dollars for hosting at a specialized hosting for magento, they have 8 cores, 32gb of ram and we have 3000 products and about 500 visits per day maximum, which I think we are paying way too much.

In azure, I like the idea of autoscaling, I could use the azure standard linux vm instance with load balancing if needed and auto scaling up or down enabled.

Our visits are between 6am and 8pm, then visits are almost dead.

Do you think this is a good option to reduce costs? 
I am thinking I could start with one S standatd instance  (1.75gb of ram, and autoscale it).
If I select on the pricing calculator A3 instance is about 170 dollars for the entire month I doubt we will ever scale up to 14gb of ram

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/#linux

Comment: Sign up and get the 30 days free.  Even on the free service it'll give you what your current and projected costs would be.  I think it would save a fair amount.

Comment: I already used the 30 day trial long time ago for something else

Comment: Then... set up another email address and go again. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, lets do some math:)

6 am - 8pm = 14h

14h * 30d = 420h/month

420h * 0.48$/h(A4) = 201.6 $, what is below 374$ you are paying right now

i think you will pay much less if you would change to azure.